# Dialog Box disapears without being clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent, dialog

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if(a){


Intent i = new Intent();
if(type.equals("x")){
showErrorAlert("string");

                    i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    i.putExtra("label", var);
                    i.putExtra("label1", var2);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
                else if(type.equals("y")){
                    i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity3.class);
                    i.putExtra("label2", var3);
                }

                //startActivity(i);
            }

            else startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity4.class));
        }
    });

private void showErrorAlert(String errorMsg){           
    AlertDialog errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    errorDialog.setTitle("title");
    errorDialog.setMessage(errorMsg);
    errorDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Okay", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    errorDialog.show();
}
```

So what happens is the error alert shows, but it will immediately close and the next activity will appear.  I want the activity to not start until after "Okay" is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if(a){
                Intent i = new Intent();
                if(type.equals("x")){
                 showErrorAlert("string");

               }
                else if(type.equals("y")){
                    i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity3.class);
                    i.putExtra("label2", var3);
                }

                //startActivity(i);
            }

            else startActivity(new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity4.class));
        }
    });

private void showErrorAlert(String errorMsg){           
    AlertDialog errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    errorDialog.setTitle("title");
    errorDialog.setMessage(errorMsg);
    errorDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Okay", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
                    i.putExtra("label", var);
                    i.putExtra("label1", var2);
                    startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    errorDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing this, and i left out alot of my code (so there's alot more functionality I had to change with this approach), but this is similar to what i did.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move your `startActivity(i);` to inside if (or) else (or) both blocks depending on where you need.

Comment: Tried that, still does the same thing.

Comment: Have you verified that else part is not working? Can edit the question and post latest code?

Comment: Yeah everything is working properly, except the dialog box disapears almost immediately without being clicked.  I moved the startActivity(i) to within the if(x) statement at the end and did the same thing.

Comment: Please update question with latest code. That may give some idea on what you have changed and what else missing.

Comment: I would try it by moving code in if block to onClick on showErrorAlert

Answer (score 0):

Place startActivity(i); inside the onClick method in your dialog like this:

```
private void showErrorAlert(String errorMsg){           
        AlertDialog errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        errorDialog.setTitle("title");
        errorDialog.setMessage(errorMsg);
        errorDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Okay", new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        errorDialog.show();
    }
```